# App ionic com nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic

Estou tentando entender o ionic, eu fiz uma rest api no nodejs e consumi a api no ionic com angular. O ionic na porta 4200, e o nodejs na 3000. No entanto surgiu uma dúvida.
Caso eu quisesse publicar o app como eu teria de fazer? Eu teria de juntar o nodejs ao angular e rodar tudo só numa porta?

Answer (score -2):

A resposta curta é Não.
basicamente quando você precisa publicar uma aplicação. você terá um ambiente para sua API um servidor tipo [Amazon AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/) e seu app será publicado na Google Play, Apple Store ou disponibilizando um apk (testes, homologação, validações, etc).

Para mais informações creio que você precise pesquisar sobre o [ionic build](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/cli/build/#:%7E:text=ionic%20build%20will%20perform%20an,platforms%20that%20you%27ve%20installed.)

No angular sei que é possível rodar uma aplicação com ***--host 0.0.0.0*** que permite usar a sua aplicação na sua rede local o que vai permitir você simular essa situação do seu dispositivo usar a API que esta em outro dispositivo.